# How Can I Download This Video?

Tags: video

My daughter was on the local TV news and I want to download the video to keep forever:

http://www.wlns.com/story/20524251/early-flu-season-hits-michigan-hard

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be able to use, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/ for FireFox

Comment: Have you considered contacting the station?

Comment: I installed it and now all the videos on the page are gone.

Comment: @dave I just sent them an email. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all you need to thank me :3

I had to:

1. Decode and look through all flash variables.
2. Deobfuscate the javascript files.
3. Seek through some asp/xml files.
4. No that's pretty much it...

**URL'S**

- http://wlns.videodownload.worldnow.com/WLNS_20130107182005470AC.mp4
- http://wlns.videodownload.worldnow.com/WLNS_20130107182005470AB.flv
- http://wlns.videodownload.worldnow.com/WLNS_20130107182005470AE.3gp

Comment: thank you! I'd upvote if I had the street cred.